# ref() of tensor not equal in dataset. Why?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am very confused by the following behavior. Take this program:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# %% Train dataset
(ds_train_original, ds_test_original), ds_info = tfds.load(
    "mnist",
    split=["train", "test"],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

iterator = iter(ds_train_original)
el = iterator.get_next()[0]
el[0].ref() == el[0].ref()   # <- this should be True
```

The last line IMO should return `True`. However, this is `False`.
I cannot understand why.

According to the [ref](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#ref) documentation:

> Returns a hashable reference object to this Tensor. The primary use case for this API is to put tensors in a set/dictionary.

My understanding is that you should be able to use the ref() to check for equality between Tensor.
Here the problem doesn't happen anymore once I have extracted the ref.
For example, this is True:

```
a_ref = el[0].ref()
a_deref = a_ref.deref()
another_ref = a_deref.ref()
a_ref == another_ref
```

So the "problem" seems confined to extracting the ref() from `iterator`.

Can anybody explain to me what is happening and why `el[0].ref() == el[0].ref()` is `False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/52537) on Github, it seems like the only viable solution is to compare the samples values, since only [weakrefs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) are created.

Thus the solution is:

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

# %% Train dataset
(ds_train_original, ds_test_original), ds_info = tfds.load(
    "mnist",
    split=["train", "test"],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

iterator = iter(ds_train_original)
el = iterator.get_next()[0]
(el[0].numpy() == el[0].numpy()).all()
```